# Function pointer type cannot be used for a function prototype

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, function-pointers, function-prototypes

I'd like to know why the following snippet does not work:

```
typedef void (*MYFUNC_PTR)(int a);
MYFUNC_PTR myFunc;

void myFunc(int a)
{

}
```

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. The source file is ".c", but I tried the same with ".cpp". The error I'm getting is

```
Error   C2365   'myFunc': redefinition; previous definition was 'data variable'
```

NOTE: I assumed this code would work because Microsoft mentions a similar snippet (which does not work either, as I tested that one, too), for example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nc-ntddk-pcreate_thread_notify_routine).

EDIT: I thought maybe this only works in one of the newer C++ standards, but that's not the case either, as I tried C++17.

Comment: You cannot have a variable and a function with the name same in a single scope

Comment: You've declared a pointer variable named `myFunc`, then tried to define a function with the same name.  It's a name conflict.  It's no different than doing:  `int f;` followed by `int f(void) {}`.  A variable and a function with the same name.  Conflict.

Comment: I did consider the fact that the typedef is for a function pointer, but I was confused because Microsoft recommended this.

Comment: @PhantomR - Microsoft made a mistake in their documentation. Or perhaps intended for the docs to be correct but ended up writing the code another way. It's an error on their part, either way.

Comment: @PhantomR Microsoft doesn't *recommend it*, they simply made a typo in their documentation. In other docs that describe callbacks, they don't show a variable declaration and a function declaration together, like your linked doc does

Comment: The MSDN documentation has a bug.  They should not have used the same name for the global variable as they did for the global function.

Comment: I actually interpreted the first line not as a global variable declaration, but as a  prototype declaration, like in the example below, which actually works (because DRIVER_INITIALIZE is not typedef-ed as a pointer). To be honest, I tend to think what they wanted to show was a prototype and not a global variable declaration.  Here's the link mentioned above: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nc-wdm-driver_initialize

Answer (score 2):

A function pointer isn't the same thing as a function declaration, so this simply doesn't work. You can do this, however:

```
typedef void(*MYFUNC_PTR)(int a);
MYFUNC_PTR myFunc;

void someFunc(int a)
{

}

int main() {
    myFunc = someFunc;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought the same after seeing the error, but the fact that Microsoft recommends this kind of construction confused me..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the type of `myFunc` is a function pointer, not a function. After that you're defining `myFunc` as a function (, of course), they don't match.

You can change the `typedef` for `MYFUNC_PTR` to function, then

```
typedef void(MYFUNC_PTR)(int a);
MYFUNC_PTR myFunc;
void myFunc(int a)
{

}
```

[LIVE](https://rextester.com/TEFP5227)

Comment: Indeed, I also found out that this works. Sadly, Microsoft only offers the "P" (pointer) variants for some of the function types. I do not understand why they say the original construction would work..